# Build array based on JSON api response

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

Below is the JSON response from api in angularjs,

```
{
"counts": 
[
  [
    {
      "xcount": 0.0,
      "ycount": 0.0,
      "month": 4

    },
    {
      "xcount": 0.0,
      "ycount": 0.0,
      "month": 5

    },
    {
      "xcount": 0.0,
      "ycount": 2.85,
      "month": 6
    },
    {
      "xcount": 8.85,
      "ycount": 0.0,
      "month": 6
    },
    {
      "xcount": 10.17,
      "ycount": 0.0,
      "month": 7
    },
    {
      "xcount": 0.0,
      "ycount": 2.85,
      "month": 7
    },
    {
      "xcount": 12.0,
      "ycount": 0.0,
      "month": 8
    },
    {
      "xcount": 0.0,
      "ycount": 2.85,
      "month": 8
    },
    {
      "xcount": 0.0,
      "ycount": 2.85,
      "month": 9
    },
    {
      "xcount": 11.0,
      "ycount": 0.0,
      "month": 9
    }
  ]
]
}
```

And as per my requirement i want above response as below

```
{
"counts": 
[
  [
    {
      "xcount": 0.0,
      "ycount": 0.0,
      "month": 4

    },
    {
      "xcount": 0.0,
      "ycount": 0.0,
      "month": 5

    },
    {
      "xcount": 8.85,
      "ycount": 2.85,
      "month": 6
    },

    {
      "xcount": 10.17,
      "ycount": 2.85,
      "month": 7
    },
    {
      "xcount": 12.0,
      "ycount": 2.85,
      "month": 8
    },
    {
      "xcount": 11.0,
      "ycount": 2.85,
      "month": 9
    }
  ]
]
```

}

Comment: What is the difference between the two?

Comment: Original has two entries with same month that i want to combine, I cannot change into the api as of now. So have to handle on UI side.

Comment: This looks like a "do it for me" kind of question. Can you add what you've tried, and explain further in-detail what you require. i.e. I want to remove duplicate months. You need to add these details in order to make the question more readable and answerable.

Comment: Its not just removing duplicates! Its combining the same key (month) element .
I was trying to solve it on backend side using reflection but could not get any solution,so now i am trying on UI side.

Comment: So the idea is to remove objects with duplicating dates?

Comment: @ManojSolanki Add those details to the question.

Comment: @DaneBrouwer i was trying to do it but i am getting page not found there. Somehow i cannot edit my post!

Comment: [You mean this link doesn't work?](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61079512/edit)

Comment: yeah. its not working for me

Comment: I think @ManojSolanki wants to unify the duplicated items, because the duplicated months have one `xcount` different than 0 and the other has `ycount` different than 0.

Comment: @ManojSolanki Would you like the numbers to be kept as Floats/Doubles? i.e. have a trailing comma 0.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var arr = {
  "counts": [
    [{
        "xcount": 0.0,
        "ycount": 0.0,
        "month": 4

      },
      {
        "xcount": 0.0,
        "ycount": 0.0,
        "month": 5

      },
      {
        "xcount": 0.0,
        "ycount": 2.85,
        "month": 6
      },
      {
        "xcount": 8.85,
        "ycount": 0.0,
        "month": 6
      },
      {
        "xcount": 10.17,
        "ycount": 0.0,
        "month": 7
      },
      {
        "xcount": 0.0,
        "ycount": 2.85,
        "month": 7
      },
      {
        "xcount": 12.0,
        "ycount": 0.0,
        "month": 8
      },
      {
        "xcount": 0.0,
        "ycount": 2.85,
        "month": 8
      },
      {
        "xcount": 0.0,
        "ycount": 2.85,
        "month": 9
      },
      {
        "xcount": 11.0,
        "ycount": 0.0,
        "month": 9
      }
    ]
  ]
}

arr.counts[0] = arr.counts[0].reduce((acc, cv, i, arr) => {
  if (!acc[cv.month]) {
    acc[cv.month] = cv;
  } else {
    acc[cv.month].xcount += cv.xcount
    acc[cv.month].ycount += cv.ycount
  }
  if (i === arr.length - 1) {
    return Object.keys(acc).map(key => acc[key])
  } else {
    return acc;
  }
}, {});

console.log(arr.counts[0]);
```

Using the `reduce` function we create a temporary object using the month number as the key. This allows us to keep track of unique entries. When we find a duplicate month, we add the `xcount` and `ycount` together. Once we reach the end of the list we return the temporary object's keys mapped to the their value. Resulting in a list containing only unique months.

Answer (score 2):

As I understood from your question is to remove duplicates months and if it's the case here is my suggestion above.

---

**Update**: got your point about combining by xcount, ycount, and added necessary changes.

```js
var arr = {
    "counts": [
      [
        {
          "month": 4,
          "xcount": 0,
          "ycount": 0
        },
        {
          "month": 5,
          "xcount": 0,
          "ycount": 0
        },
        {
          "month": 6,
          "xcount": 0,
          "ycount": 2.85
        },
        {
          "month": 6,
          "xcount": 8.85,
          "ycount": 0
        },
        {
          "month": 7,
          "xcount": 10.17,
          "ycount": 0
        },
        {
          "month": 7,
          "xcount": 0,
          "ycount": 2.85
        },
        {
          "month": 8,
          "xcount": 12,
          "ycount": 0
        },
        {
          "month": 8,
          "xcount": 0,
          "ycount": 2.85
        },
        {
          "month": 9,
          "xcount": 0,
          "ycount": 2.85
        },
        {
          "month": 9,
          "xcount": 11,
          "ycount": 0
        }
      ]
    ]
  };
  var tmpMonths = [];
  var tmpObjects = {};
  var results = [];
  for (var i=0;i<arr.counts[0].length;i++) {
      var obj = arr.counts[0][i];
      var key = "month_" + obj.month;
      if (obj.month && tmpMonths.indexOf(obj.month)===-1) {
          
          tmpMonths.push(obj.month);
          tmpObjects[key] = obj;
          results.push(obj);
      } else {
          tmpObjects[key] = {
              month: obj.month,
              xcount: obj.xcount + tmpObjects[key]["xcount"],
              ycount: obj.ycount + tmpObjects[key]["ycount"],
          };
      }
  }
  arr.counts[0] = Object.values(tmpObjects);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

Comment: And also want to combine xcount ycount of that duplicates!

Comment: you mean by combine sum of the xcount and ycoundt (+ operator)?

Comment: Like this   `{    "xcount": 8.85,   "ycount": 2.85,   "month": 6   } `

Comment: Value needs to combine not no needs to do sum of them.

Comment: Find updated code and let me know if respond to your need?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211137/discussion-between-mostav-and-manoj-solanki).